# Excel VBA: how to capture event of ca change in read-only setting? Excel file is opened over SharePoint and automatically set to read-only

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I have an *.xlsm file that is to be accessed department-wide over SharePoint. The problem is when this file is opened it is open in read-only automatically (presumably because of SharePoint settings). The prompt at the top of the window is :

`Server Read-Only  This workbook was opened from a server in read-only mode. [Edit Workbook]`

- I know how to capture the read-only setting when the file is opened and to configure my file accordingly
- I know how to prompt the user to change the read-only setting when the workbook is being opened.

This is my problem:

- I don't know how to capture the event when a user presses [Edit Workbook] and the file is no longer read-only.

My only workaround is to constantly check the read-only setting of the file at every execution of any code, which I'd rather not do because of performance hit and it might not always work.

So I'm stumped. Any ideas on how to capture this event?

Comment: Quite simply - you can't. It's part of Excel's built in security which can't be automated for good reason. The best option you have is to have some code in the `Workbook_open` event which will only run _after_ the user has pressed the edit workbook button. Why do you need to capture this event anyway?

Comment: @MacroMan the problem is that the `Workbook_open` event is configured by Excel to be triggered before the `Edit Workbook` prompt appears. As to the reasons why I need this, the tool is configured to send actionable items around a multinational team. I don't want users to be able to send around actions without a record of these actions.

Comment: No code will run before that prompt has been dealt with - it's a security prompt designed to _prevent_ any code from running without the user's permission. If the `Workbook_Open` event has run it's because the user has pressed the edit workbook button.

Comment: Oh hang on - do you mean you wantt o capture the point at where the workbook _stops_ being read-only and suddenly becomes read/write. Not necessarily that button being pressed?

Comment: @MacroMan Yes, what I want is capture when the workbook stops being read-only and becomes read/write. PS: actually I have plenty of code which does successfully run while the workbook in read-only. That works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.

When the file is opened over SharePoint, the file is automatically opened as read-only with a yellow prompt asking the user if the file is to be edited.

The command `ThisWorkbook.LockServerFile` will behave just as if `[Edit Workbook]` had been pressed. Placing it in the `Workbook_Open()` Event will execute this command every time this file is opened. The problem is that if this command is executed on a local drive, this will return an error, so you need to have some error handlers or detect your environment.

This is a link to the MSDN article: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838567.aspx